# Why should I need the push function?

Tags: javascript, svg

I don't can't understand what's the use of the function push and how does it help.
1 - Why should I need the line code?

```
circles.push(newCircle);
```

2 – I copy this code to html file and the code is not running, should I miss something here?
Thx

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Your title here</title>

<script type = "text/javascript" language = "Javascript">
<!-- Hide from older browsers;
var svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
var svgElement = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'svg');
document.body.appendChild(svgElement);

var Circle = function(x,y,size){
    this.element = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;

    this.dx = 10*(Math.random()-0.5);
    this.dy = 10*(Math.random()-0.5);

    this.element.setAttribute('cx', this.x+'px');
    this.element.setAttribute('cy', this.y+'px');
    this.element.setAttribute('r', this.size+'px');
    this.element.setAttribute('stroke', 'black');
    this.element.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2px');
    this.element.setAttribute('fill', 'red');

    svgElement.appendChild(this.element);    
};

Circle.prototype.update = function(){
    this.x += this.dx;
    this.y += this.dy;
    this.element.setAttribute('cx', this.x+'px');
    this.element.setAttribute('cy', this.y+'px');
};


var circles = [];
for (var i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
    var newCircle = new Circle(100,100,10);
    circles.push(newCircle);     
}

window.setInterval(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i< circles.length; i++) {
        circles[i].update();
    }    
}, 30);




// end hide -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Insert HTML here -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like your missing the namespace in your <html> tag?

Comment: actually it works. http://jsfiddle.net/eU32w/

Comment: @DimitriAdamou The fiddle is working, because anything in the upperleft block is included within `<body> ... </body>`.

Answer (score 2):

1. [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is an array method, which adds `Circle` instances to the collection (array) `circles`.

   The `circles` array is used as a reference set in the block at the end of your code snippet `circles[i].update()`.
2. You're using the `document.body` reference before the `<body>` is encountered. As a result, `document.body` is `undefined`, and your code throws an error.
   Either put the `<script>` block within `<body>`, or defer the script via `window.onload=function(){ ... code here... }`, or the `defer` attribute on the script tag.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `push` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) for more details. Here's an example of how it works:

   `var sports = ["soccer", "baseball"];`

   `sports.push("football", "swimming");`

   `// Now, sports = ["soccer", "baseball", "football", "swimming"]`
2. What's not working?

Comment: Thanks, do you have more sample simular to circles.push(newCircle);

Answer (score 0):

Ahhaha, that's my code. I wondered why it looked so familiar. You've put it in the wrong place. In the original fiddle I made for you it was run in response to the window load event.

You can either do that yourself, or just put the script tag in the body rather than the head.

To wait for the load event, replace the line `document.body.appendChild(svgElement);` with this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.body.appendChild(svgElement);
});
```

Comment: thx can you have more examle like this with push function I am not fill 100% understanding with svg ?

Comment: the 'push function' is just a way of adding items to an array. It has nothing to do with svg. I was just saving all the circles so i could loop through them for the animation.